# Facebook credits graph api - all transactions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, credits

I'm looking through the documentation, trying to figure out if there is a way to list all settled transaction for a given month.
So far im using: https://graph.facebook.com/appId/payments?status=settled&since=start&until=end&access_token=access_token

However it will not allow me to get details for the entire month (as described in the documentation), and it seems like a very difficult way to gather all this information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is still no way of doing this. Only solution is to loop the token and get for each specefic date

Comment: I thought so too, but then i started to look at browser based games, like Zynga Mafia Wars, and apparently they do not suffer this problem. At least not when i test with Safari.

So basicly it should be possible ?